# Python Update Inventory in Shopify by variant SKU

Tags: python, shopify

I am trying to update shopify variant's inventory quantity by SKU,
but i am not getting how to do it by there dev docs,

here is what i've done,

i installed https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_python_api and written below code, and the code is working fine, but not sure how to get variant by sku and update its available quantity on shopify.

```
shop_url = "https://%s:%s@abc.myshopify.com/admin/api/%s" % (API_KEY, PASSWORD, API_VERSION)
shopify.ShopifyResource.set_site(shop_url)
shop = shopify.Shop.current()
product = shopify.Product.find(4398162804809)
print(product)
```

Answer (score 1):

SKU's are not unique values. You can have all of your variants to have the same SKU which is not usable. That's why you can't update them by SKU, but only by ID.

There is no way to get variants by SKU with the REST API if I'm not mistaken.

For that you will need to look into GraphQL:

```
query {
  productVariants(first: 1, query: "sku:YOUR_SKU") {
    edges {
      node {
        id
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Tanks for your reply, but how to use GraphQl in python file? while inserting above code into py file, its giving me the indentation error,
and after getting variant id of product, how to update quantity of shopify?

Comment: @MalikMuhammadShahidKhan Look into https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_python_api there is a GraphQL section there. In addition the Shopify docs about the productVariants GraphQL https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/graphql/reference/object/productvariant

Answer (score 0):

i used graphql query and it returns me the following details,

```
{'data': {'productVariants': {'edges': [{'node': {'id': 'gid://shopify/ProductVariant/31281648828489'}}]}}, 'extensions': {'cost': {'requestedQueryCost': 3, 'actualQueryCost': 3, 'throttleStatus': {'maximumAvailable': 1000.0, 'currentlyAvailable': 997, 'restoreRate': 50.0}}}}
```

Now i am looking for exact graphql query which should return me the exact product id and variant id.